# Adding true hyperlink support to TRichEdit

Tags: html, delphi, browser, delphi-xe7, trichedit

I need support for "friendly name hyperlink" in TRichEdit and all solutions I have found are based on autoURLs ([EM_AUTOURLDETECT](http://www.scalabium.com/faq/dct0146.htm)) which works by detecting strings entered by user that start with www (or http).

But I want to place links on strings that does not start with www. Example: '[Download](http://www.SomeSite.com/download)'.

Comment: Your link uses a native property of TRichEdit, but you need to do something a little more complex than that, I think. You are probably using the wrong control for what you need, but it is hard to say with such scant information. A TRichEdit is designed as a text editor, so, for instance, how in such a control could a user type in a non-visible bit of text such as you need? If it is read only, then you probably need some sort of HTML viewer instead of a TRichEdit

Comment: ITextRange2.SetUrl https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/murrays/2009/09/24/richedit-friendly-name-hyperlinks/

Comment: For older versions you'll have to use the techniques described in the article

Comment: I miss something. The article say that I use ITextRange.Expand to read an existing link. But how do I create a new link (my original question) or how do I modify an existing link?

Comment: "In RichEdit 4.1, the only way to insert a friendly name hyperlink is to read in "the corresponding RTF" - this means parsing the whole rtf structure, changing one link and 'uploading' the RTF structure back into the control for rendering. And, if I have more than one link, I have to find out which link was clicked. Nasty hack :)

Comment: @remylebeau - that question is about "Detect click on URL in RichEdit" and its answer does not EVEN BY FAR answers this question.

Comment: @NAZCA: Actually it does, by showing how to react to hyperlink clicks and launching the clicked URL. Creating a Friendly Name Hyperlink is simply a matter of how the `CFE_LINK` text is formatted and then parsed in the `EN_LINK` notification.  See the update to my answer below for an example.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to do the following:

1. send the RichEdit an [`EM_SETEVENTMASK`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774238.aspx) message to enable the `ENM_LINK` flag.  Do this once after the RichEdit has been created, and then do it again every time the RichEdit receives a `CM_RECREATEWND` message.
2. select the desired text you want to turn into a link. You can use the RichEdit's `SelStart` and `SelLength` properties, or send the RichEdit an [`EM_SETSEL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761661.aspx) or [`EM_EXSETSEL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb788007.aspx) message.  Either way, then send the RichEdit an [`EM_SETCHARFORMAT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774230.aspx) message with a [`CHARFORMAT2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787883.aspx) struct to enable the `CFE_LINK` effect on the selected text.
3. subclass the RichEdit's `WindowProc` property to handle [`CN_NOTIFY(EN_LINK)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787970.aspx) and `CM_RECREATEWND` messages.  When `EN_LINK` is received, you can use `ShellExecute/Ex()` to launch the desired URL.

For example:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ComCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    RichEdit1: TRichEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    PrevRichEditWndProc: TWndMethod;
    procedure InsertHyperLink(const HyperlinkText: string);
    procedure SetRichEditMasks;
    procedure RichEditWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses
  Winapi.RichEdit, Winapi.ShellAPI;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PrevRichEditWndProc := RichEdit1.WindowProc;
  RichEdit1.WindowProc := RichEditWndProc;

  SetRichEditMasks;

  RichEdit1.Text := 'Would you like to Download Now?';

  RichEdit1.SelStart := 18;
  RichEdit1.SelLength := 12;    
  InsertHyperLink('Download Now');
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  InsertHyperLink('Another Link');
end;

procedure TForm1.InsertHyperLink(const HyperlinkText: string);
var
  Fmt: CHARFORMAT2;
  StartPos: Integer;
begin
  StartPos := RichEdit1.SelStart;
  RichEdit1.SelText := HyperlinkText;

  RichEdit1.SelStart := StartPos;
  RichEdit1.SelLength := Length(HyperlinkText);

  FillChar(Fmt, SizeOf(Fmt), 0);
  Fmt.cbSize := SizeOf(Fmt);
  Fmt.dwMask := CFM_LINK;
  Fmt.dwEffects := CFE_LINK;

  SendMessage(RichEdit1.Handle, EM_SETCHARFORMAT, SCF_SELECTION, LPARAM(@Fmt));

  RichEdit1.SelStart := StartPos + Length(HyperlinkText);
  RichEdit1.SelLength := 0;
end;

procedure TForm1.SetRichEditMasks;
var
  Mask: DWORD;
begin
  Mask := SendMessage(RichEdit1.Handle, EM_GETEVENTMASK, 0, 0);
  SendMessage(RichEdit1.Handle, EM_SETEVENTMASK, 0, Mask or ENM_LINK);
  SendMessage(RichEdit1.Handle, EM_AUTOURLDETECT, 1, 0);
end;

procedure TForm1.RichEditWndProc(var Message: TMessage);
type
  PENLINK = ^ENLINK;
var
  tr: TEXTRANGE;
  str: string;
  p: PENLINK;
begin
  PrevRichEditWndProc(Message);

  case Message.Msg of
    CN_NOTIFY: begin
     if TWMNotify(Message).NMHdr.code = EN_LINK then
      begin
        P := PENLINK(Message.LParam);
        if p.msg = WM_LBUTTONUP then
        begin
          SetLength(str, p.chrg.cpMax - p.chrg.cpMin);
          tr.chrg := p.chrg;
          tr.lpstrText := PChar(str);
          SendMessage(RichEdit1.Handle, EM_GETTEXTRANGE, 0, LPARAM(@tr));

          if str = 'Download Now' then
          begin
            ShellExecute(Handle, nil, 'http://www.SomeSite.com/download', nil, nil, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
          end
          else if str = 'Another Link' then
          begin
            // do something else
          end;
        end;
      end;
    end;

    CM_RECREATEWND: begin
      SetRichEditMasks;
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

---

**Update**: Per MSDN:

[RichEdit Friendly Name Hyperlinks](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/murrays/2009/09/24/richedit-friendly-name-hyperlinks/)

> In RichEdit, the hyperlink field entity is represented by character formatting effects, as contrasted to delimiters which are used to structure math objects. As such, these hyperlinks cannot be nested, although in RichEdit 5.0 and later they can be adjacent to one another. The whole hyperlink has the character formatting effects of `CFE_LINK` and `CFE_LINKPROTECTED`, while autoURLs only have the `CFE_LINK` attribute. The `CFE_LINKPROTECTED` is included for the former so that the autoURL scanner skips over friendly name links. The instruction part, i.e., the URL, has the `CFE_HIDDEN` attribute as well, since it’s not supposed to be displayed. The URL itself is enclosed in ASCII double quotes and preceded by the string `“HYPERLINK “`. Since `CFE_HIDDEN` plays an integral role in friendly name hyperlinks, it cannot be used in the name.
>
> For example, in WordPad, which uses RichEdit, a hyperlink with the name MSN would have the plain text
>
> ```
> HYPERLINK “http://www.msn.com”MSN
> ```
>
> The whole link would have `CFE_LINK` and `CFE_LINKPROTECTED` character formatting attributes and all but the MSN would have the `CFE_HIDDEN` attribute.

This can be simulated easily in code:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ...
  RichEdit1.Text := 'Would you like to Download Now?';

  RichEdit1.SelStart := 18;
  RichEdit1.SelLength := 12;    
  InsertHyperLink('Download Now', 'http://www.SomeSite.com/downloads');
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  InsertHyperLink('A Text Link');
end;

procedure TForm1.InsertHyperLink(const HyperlinkText: string; const HyperlinkURL: string = '');
var
  HyperlinkPrefix, FullHyperlink: string;
  Fmt: CHARFORMAT2;
  StartPos: Integer;
begin
  if HyperlinkURL <> '' then
  begin
    HyperlinkPrefix := Format('HYPERLINK "%s"', [HyperlinkURL]);
    FullHyperlink := HyperlinkPrefix + HyperlinkText;
  end else begin
    FullHyperlink := HyperlinkText;
  end;

  StartPos := RichEdit1.SelStart;
  RichEdit1.SelText := FullHyperlink;

  RichEdit1.SelStart := StartPos;
  RichEdit1.SelLength := Length(FullHyperlink);

  FillChar(Fmt, SizeOf(Fmt), 0);
  Fmt.cbSize := SizeOf(Fmt);
  Fmt.dwMask := CFM_LINK;
  Fmt.dwEffects := CFE_LINK;
  if HyperlinkURL <> '' then
  begin
    // per MSDN: "RichEdit doesn’t allow the CFE_LINKPROTECTED attribute to be
    // set directly by programs. Maybe it will allow it someday after enough
    // testing is completed to ensure that things cannot go awry"...
    //
    {
    Fmt.dwMask := Fmt.dwMask or CFM_LINKPROTECTED;
    Fmt.dwEffects := Fmt.dwEffects or CFE_LINKPROTECTED;
    }
  end;

  SendMessage(RichEdit1.Handle, EM_SETCHARFORMAT, SCF_SELECTION, LPARAM(@Fmt));

  if HyperlinkURL <> '' then
  begin
    RichEdit1.SelStart := StartPos;
    RichEdit1.SelLength := Length(HyperlinkPrefix);

    FillChar(Fmt, SizeOf(Fmt), 0);
    Fmt.cbSize := SizeOf(Fmt);
    Fmt.dwMask := CFM_HIDDEN;
    Fmt.dwEffects := CFE_HIDDEN;

    SendMessage(RichEdit1.Handle, EM_SETCHARFORMAT, SCF_SELECTION, LPARAM(@Fmt));
  end;

  RichEdit1.SelStart := StartPos + Length(FullHyperlink);
  RichEdit1.SelLength := 0;
end;
```

And then handled in the `EN_LINK` notification by parsing the clicked hyperlink text:

```
uses
  ..., System.StrUtils;

...

SendMessage(RichEdit1.Handle, EM_GETTEXTRANGE, 0, LPARAM(@tr));

// Per MSDN: "The ENLINK notification structure contains a CHARRANGE with
// the start and end character positions of the actual URL (IRI, file path
// name, email address, etc.) that typically appears in a browser URL
// window. This doesn’t include the “HYPERLINK ” string nor the quotes in
// the hidden part. For the MSN link above, it identifies only the
// http://www.msn.com characters in the backing store."
//
// However, without the CFM_LINKPROTECTED flag, the CHARRANGE will report
// the positions of the entire "HYPERLINK ..." string instead, so just strip
// off what is not needed...
//
if StartsText('HYPERLINK "', str) then
begin
  Delete(str, 1, 11);
  Delete(str, Pos('"', str), MaxInt);
end;

if (str is a URL) then begin
  ShellExecute(Handle, nil, PChar(str), nil, nil, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
end
else begin
  // do something else
end;
```

Comment: @NAZCA: Sure, if you are loading external RTF, like a document file.  But if you are simply populating the RichEdit with your own text in code, it is easy enough to insert hyperlinks where needed, as demonstrated above. And it is not hard to store the actual URLs in the text, if you don't want to keep track of them in code.  For instance, by embedding and hiding a URL after its hyperlink text, and then adjusting the `EM_GETTEXTEX` range accordingly.

Comment: @NAZCA: No, by using the `CFE_HIDDEN` effect, just like actual Friendly Name Hyperlinks do. I updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Note: SetLength(str, chrg.cpMax - chrg.cpMin) - This works only when you have in RichEdit one link. If the text in RichEdit is more complex, the length of the 'str' var needs to be equal with the number of chars in the RichEdit, including the hidden ones.

Comment: There is a problem: when inserting a second link, the first link loses its 'hidden attribute' and becomes visible. Example: https://ufile.io/25efb

Comment: @NAZCA: the `CHARRANGE` provided by `EN_LINK` includes only the characters for the link being clicked (read the documentation!), so `chrg.cpMax - chrg.cpMin` is the correct `String` length. My mistake was using `EM_GETTEXTEX`, I meant to use [`EM_GETTEXTRANGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774199.aspx) instead. I have corrected that now.

Comment: @NAZCA: However, that being said, having multiple links in the RichEdit works just fine (I tested it). Your example is coded wrong. You are manipulating the RichEdit's `Text` property, which loses all existing formatting. To insert a hyperlink into existing text, you need to use the `SelText` property instead, eg: `RichEdit1.SelText := HyperLnkTxt;`. If there is a current selection (`SelLength > 0`), the new text will replace the selection. Otherwise, the new text will simply be inserted at the current caret position. I updated my answer to show this.

Comment: "You are manipulating the RichEdit's Text" - Yes. Now that you mention it, the problem is more than obvious. I was so dumb not to see that. THANKS AGAIN!

Comment: @RemyLebeau sorry if this is a stupid question, but where does the code for handling the `EN_LINK` notification go

Comment: @WiliamCardoso that is covered in my answer : "*subclass the RichEdit's `WindowProc` property to handle `CN_NOTIFY(EN_LINK)` and `CM_RECREATEWND` messages.*" I even showed an example of that (see the `TForm1.RichEditWndProc()` method)

Comment: @RemyLebeau this is great working in TRichEdit, but I want to use it in TDBRichEdit. It works fine, unitil you go to another record and come back. Then are all the hyperlinks not longer recognized as hyperlinks. The content of the field is the same, but it has lost its link properties.
Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: @Evert-JanModderkolk You would have to recreate all of the hyperlinks every time the DBRichEdit is refreshed when the active record changes to a different record.